# Heroku build error - could it be npm version issue?

Tags: heroku

For some reason my app, which has been building without any issues for some time, has stopped building on Heroku giving me the following error. It builds and runs locally without issue.

Can anyone explain what might be going wrong?

I have only made minor changes between versions. I have tried uninstalling/installing bcrypt but that doesn't fix it. The only other change that I can think of is that I have updated npm - could that have anything to do with it?

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
    
-----> Creating runtime environment
    
    NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
    NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
    NODE_ENV=production
    NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
    NODE_VERBOSE=false
    
-----> Installing binaries
    engines.node (package.json):  >=14.0.0
    engines.npm (package.json):   >=6.0.0
    
    Resolving node version >=14.0.0...
    Downloading and installing node 15.13.0...
    Bootstrapping npm >=6.0.0 (replacing 7.7.6)...
    npm >=6.0.0 installed
    
-----> Restoring cache
    - node_modules
    
-----> Installing dependencies
    Installing node modules
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path /tmp/build_ec49f9ec/node_modules/bcrypt
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.13.0 | linux | x64
    npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.6.9 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
    npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.13.0/node-v15.13.0-headers.tar.gz
    npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.13.0/node-v15.13.0-headers.tar.gz
    npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.13.0/SHASUMS256.txt
    npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.13.0/SHASUMS256.txt
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_ec49f9ec/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_ec49f9ec/node_modules/bcrypt/build/config.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_ec49f9ec/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/app/.cache/node-gyp/15.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/app/.cache/node-gyp/15.13.0',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/tmp/build_ec49f9ec/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/app/.cache/node-gyp/15.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/tmp/build_ec49f9ec/node_modules/bcrypt',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
    npm ERR! gyp: Undefined variable module_name in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_ec49f9ec/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1088-aws
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_ec49f9ec/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_ec49f9ec/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_ec49f9ec/node_modules/bcrypt
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.13.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.8NcBI/_logs/2021-04-05T15_21_07_279Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Versions in package.json are the invisible enemy :(

Try one of these approaches:

#### option 1

- delete your package-lock.json
- push this change to heroku

#### option 2

- delete your local node_modules
- backup your package-lock.json and delete it
- npm install, npm run start, etc and verify if it is working in your localhost
- a new package-lock.json will be generated.
- push this change to heroku
- try on heroku